# When does meteor store login token during authentication?

Tags: meteor

I need to set login token cookie. It works fine, but when I login from one user to another it seems that it stores wrong token that cannot be used to retrieve user from db. Here how I tried to do it:

onLogin hook on client:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
        $.cookie('X-Auth-Token', Accounts._storedLoginToken(), { path: '/' });
    });
```

Tracker:

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
        $.cookie('X-Auth-Token', Accounts._storedLoginToken(), { path: '/' });
    });
```

Login callback:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(){
     $.cookie('X-Auth-Token', Accounts._storedLoginToken(), { path: '/' });
});
```

None of them worked. What worked though is simple manual click event which set login token. I would login to a new user and then click a button which sets login token cookie and token is correct then. So I think this delay helps (as I said all my tries to do that right after new login fails). My question is - when it is ok to use Accounts._storedLoginToken() after new login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some debugging and reading source code I found out that Meteor.logoutOtherClients() modifies login token and I was invoking this method in my login callback (when user logs in it is logged out from other devices). I didn't solve it and simply removed this method as I was rethinking my use case and decided that I don't need to logout other clients. After that it started working perfectly.